# How do I change the CoCo 3 color palette before running a Color Computer ROM Pak?

Tags: color-computer, program-pak, coco

The Radio Shack game *Wildcatting* uses the wrong color set when being played on a Color Computer 3 with an RGB monitor.

How can I choose the correct color set before this game automatically executes?

Answer (score 11):

If you have a Multi-Pak, put the Program Pak in Slot 1 and set the switch to slot 2. Turn on the Multi-Pak and then the Color Computer 3.

type: `PALETTE RGB` to set the proper color set.

type: `POKE 65407,0` to switch the Multi-Pak to slot 1.

The game will then automatically start with the proper colors.

Comment: Can you do it without a MPI? For instance someone might only have a Y-cable, or nothing.

Comment: How were you able to answer your own question at the exact same time you asked it?